# How to write an Attribute executing code BEFORE and AFTER a method in C# .NET6

Tags: c#

I need to call a Method AFTER every constructor call.

```cs
public class Spam
{
  public int stored_var = 1;
  private int evaluated_var;

  // EMPTY CTOR
  [InitializeCaller()]  // <== what I need
  public Spam()
  {
    this.Initialize(); // NOT WHAT I WANT
  }

  // CTOR
  [InitializeCaller()]  // <== what I need
  public Spam(int a)
  {
    this.stored_var = a;
    this.Initialize(); // NOT WHAT I WANT
  }

  public void Initialize()
  {
    // here some complex evaluation
    this.evaluated_var = this.stored_var + 1;
  }
}
```

1. I can't place the Initialize commands inside the CTOR. The problem arises from JSON deserialization: the deserializer calls the empty CTOR to generate an instance of the object and THEN it fills the data. So all the evaluations are made with the default field values and not with the ones from the JSON. I need to call the `Initialize()` AFTER the constructor.
2. I can't call manually the 'Initialize()` after ALL the constructors: the class and the have to be consistent
3. the [Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute) seems to be able to attach info and do something BEFORE but I don't understand if it is possible to to something AFTER the method
4. It would be great to have something acting like [python decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator)

thank you!

Comment: happy debugging with this magic IMHO

Comment: Attributes are just metadata. They do not execute any code at runtime on their own. They can be *used* by other pieces of code to do things like IL rewriting, but on their own they're entirely static. What you probably need to do is hook into whatever mechanisms your JSON serialization framework is offering for this sort of thing, or else go the way of Automapper.

Comment: @daremachine: the other option is to rely on my memory ... I think it's even worst! ;-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert right: actually I need to call it AFTER the deserializer. So no way to use "decorators" ... sadly!

Comment: The usual attribute contains metadata, not code! You must use some AOP tool, which will make changes to the code at the compilation stage.

Comment: Please could you disambiguate a little? There seem to be two different questions: _How to write Attribute executing code..._ but also _I need to call a Method AFTER every constructor call_. Then, to me anyway, the real X problem seems to be wanting some code auto-run after _any_ CTor but more problematically after Json deserializer is done setting the `JsonProperties` of the object. Can you help us hone in on the most important aspect of you post? The reason I ask is that the `Attribute` scheme might not be the fastest way to get where you want, but it _is_ your main question.

Comment: As-written my instinct would be to read up more on DispatchProxy but after seeing it specifically dealing with constructors and deserialization I would look into a custom `JsonConverter` instead.

Comment: You can check out the callbacks (such as `OnSerialized`), provided by the JSON serialization library you are using. Callbacks typically solves such a tasks by somehow defining special magick "methods" which are called automatically during deserialization. And these methods can do all preprocessing and postprocessing of the object. For Newtonsoft.JSON see here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm. For System.Text.JSON - here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#callbacks